# Java 8 Optional injection with Sprint Boot 2

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Posting here before annoying the Spring Boot team on GitHub! :)

Unless I'm doing something incredibly wrong (and it may very well be), I've noticed a *weird* pattern when injecting an `Optional` bean with Spring Boot (2.0.3.RELEASE).

The following works and I do understand why:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OptionalInjection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext = SpringApplication.run(OptionalInjection.class, args);
        Foo foo = configurableApplicationContext.getBean(Foo.class);
        System.out.println(foo.getOptionalString());
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        public String optionalString() {
            return someMethodThatReturnsAnOptional()
                    .orElse(null); // I so don't like unwrapping the Optional here!
        }

    }

    @Component
    static class Foo {

        private final Optional<String> optionalString;

        @Autowired
        public Foo(Optional<String> optionalString) {
            this.optionalString = optionalString;
        }

        public Optional<String> getOptionalString() {
            return optionalString;
        }

    }

    private static Optional<String> someMethodThatReturnsAnOptional() {
        return Optional.of("Some string!");
    }

}
```

But what I was actually trying to do is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OptionalInjection {

    // ...

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        public Optional<String> optionalString() {
            return someMethodThatReturnsAnOptional(); // no Optional unwrapping!
        }

    }

    // ...

}
```

Is there a way to make the second option work?

P.S. constructor injection is a must here! :)

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Spring Boot. You can remove Spring Boot from your example and see the same behaviour with pure Spring Framework.

Comment: I didn't see any information about the optional usage as a bean. I tried and which is rather annoying/surprising is that  no exception is thrown but no bean is registered.